# 501 Errors on Facebook IFRAME

Tags: php, facebook, http-status-codes

Im loading an iframe within a facebook app but I seem to be getting a 501 error response. I do not get this error response when navigating directly to the domain I am hosting on e.g

```
 www.example.com/fbapp/
```

but when i go to

```
 aps.facebook.com/fbapp
```

I get the error.

We have a valid SSL for our site and the issue from what I can tell is sporadic at best.

I would really just like to understand why it might be happening and any preventative measures I can take.

Comment: You should probably share real URLs so this can be reviewed.

Comment: hi sorry this is a project for a big company who wouldnt want the app getting out there yet. although I will certainly post it once its live!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request from Facebook to your app is made via a POST request when loaded from Facebook - make sure your code can handle that, and check your own server's error logs as this is where the 501 error is coming from, only your own logs will be able to tell you what the issue is

Comment: thanks Igy - I will have a dig around our servers error logs and report back here if I find anything (lengthy process as we are on shared hosting and I probably wont have access to them)